# rails 3.1, How to manage URLs for a multilingual website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to know please, what is the recommended way to develop a website with two languages:

Arabic ( Right To Left )
English ( Left to Right )

URLs will have a two characters to specify the language, like:

`www.domainname.com/ar/homepage` or `www.domainname.com/en/homepage`

so, the router shall be able to add `ar`, `en` for each url ...

I know that I my controller should work for both languages, but, how to pick the right css for the chosen language ? is there a blog or tutorial for this case ?

Also, as for the data base, shall I add a field of content for each language ? what's the recommended approach for that ? for reading and writing ?

Any guidance will be more than appreciated!

Comment: Would this help you? http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/arabichelper_plugin

Comment: I would not use a plugin, since rails 4.x is deprecating plugins, that would be a dead-end solution.

Comment: You are right Ekampp, as we will be forced to upgrade to rails 4.x in the end ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use I18n and then scope the urls, but I suggest that you [read this article on I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params), to get a firmer grasp of the concept.